# How to stop Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile from deleting file

Tags: laravel

I would like to upload a file for testing but Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile keeps deleting the file, is there a way to keep it?

```
    protected function getTestFile($fileName)
{
    $file = new UploadedFile(
        base_path('tests/files/' . $fileName),
        $fileName,
        $this->getMimeType($fileName),
        null,
        true
    );

    return ['file' => $file];
}
```

and in test:

`$response = $this->call('POST', route('terms.import'), [], [], $this->getTestFile('create_terms.xls'));`